# Excel grouping on chart labels by Date/Time instead of by Date

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm creating an Excel table of 83 thousand rows.
It's a simple layout: Date/Time and number.
The Date/Time granularity is by minute.

When I use the table for a line chart I expect something like:
[image]

but instead I'm getting:
[image]

Closely inspecting, I noticed that Excel is actually grouping the data by day (and averaging the numbers) and ignoring the original granularity (minute) of the dataset.

How can I override this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I believe Excel will always group a Line Chart's values by the Date, so I don't think what you are trying to do is possible with a Line Chart.  However, you should be able to get similar results by using a Scatter Chart instead.

As an example, I created the small 6-row chart below using the "Scatter with Smooth Lines and Markers" type. However, considering the size of your dataset, you may have better results with one of the other types such as "Scatter" (no lines, just data points).

[image: screenshot]